# How to remove the line break in each string line that ends with a space using regex? Java

Tags: java, regex, string, file

I am looping through a text file line by line, and for each line I check if the line "ends with a space and a line break `\n`", then I want to cancel the line break and leave the space.

- An example:

Lets say I have a text file that includes the following text:

`Hello world, 
 this is me.`

NOTE: there is one space after "Hello world," and a line break.

- Expected result:

`Hello world, this is me.`

This is my code:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.endsWith(" ")) {
        bw.write(line.replaceFirst(" \n", " "));
    }
}
```

The regex seems not working quite well. It matches the first space without considering the line break `\n` condition! Any ideas? I just want to cancel the line break in each string line that ends with a whitespace.

- Note: the line break `\n` is not explicitly shown on the text file!

Comment: `readLine` shouldn't include `\n`, `\r` nor `\r\n`. Are you sure that line break is there? How did you test it?

Comment: @Pshemo No, its not there explicitly! I just know because the start of  the new line after each string line within the file. Could this be the problem?

Comment: "*No, its not there explicitly*" then what is the problem you are facing? What are you trying to achieve and how your code doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Pshemo I am trying to replace that line break, whether its there or not, if there was a space at the end of each line..

Comment: @bad As Pshemo said, you won't ever have a line break, because of the very definition of a *line* (string with no line break !!).

Comment: @Dici So, how to do it?

Comment: @bad There is nothing to do, your filter is pointless because it does not match any line in the world. Maybe you should give an example input file and the desired output

Comment: I am confused about "*I am trying to replace that line break, whether its there or not*". From your code it looks like you want to remove `\n` which could be at the end of line, right after space. But if `\n` is not there then there is nothing to replace, so your result should be anyway fine. Maybe post example of your input and what result you expect.

Comment: @bad.... using line in a loop that way would end up replacing the value in line with the value in next line all the time. If you want to retain it and then append next line to it continuing with a " ", you need to store it somehow and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my reading of your question, It looks like you want to turn this:

```
A line
Another line that ends with a space_
Finally the end
```

(Where the `_` represents a trailing space) into this:

```
A line
Another line that ends with a space Finally the end
```

If that is the case, this should do it (assuming your `bw` is a `BufferedWriter`):

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    /* We always write out the line (without an end-of-line character(s)) */
    bw.write(line);

    /* If the line does not end with a space, write out an end-of-line character */
    if (!line.endsWith(" ")) {
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

**Update**: You asked for an explanation of why your code doesn't work, Here is your code:

```java
/* 1 */ String line;
/* 2 */ while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
/* 3 */     if (line.endsWith(" ")) {
/* 4 */         bw.write(line.replaceFirst(" \n", " "));
/* 5 */     }
/* 6 */ }
```

Lines 1, 5, and 6 require no explanation.

- Line 2: You ask the `BufferedReader` for a line and check to see that the returned `String` is not `null`. It if was `null` then you've reached the end of your stream.
- Line 3: You check if `line` ends with a space.
- Line 4: You call `replaceFirst` on `line` and write the result to `bw`, a `BufferedWriter`.

**Problems**:

- Line 3: If `line` does *not* end with a space, you do nothing with `line`. You don't write it out at all.
- Line 4: The call to `replaceFirst` will never do anything because `" \n"` will never be matched. There have been many comments relating to this point on both the question itself and on this answer, but just so you are clear: The `String` that is returned by `BufferedReader.readLine()` will **never** contain an end-of-line character(s), as stated by [the documentation for `BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> **Returns:** A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Comment: God bless you, exactly what I tried to explain! Would you please explain how this worked, and why my code didn't work? Thank you again.

Comment: @bad then you should have adde an example, that's the best way to be understood ! Anyway, you got an answer so that's fine.

Comment: @Dici I thought my question was very clear and it didn't need an example to clarify it more. Also, I said again at the end of my question that all what I want to do is to remove the line break, if there is a space at the end of each line within that text file. But, a lot focused more on my wrong implementation rather than my one request!

Comment: @bad "*But, a lot focused more on my wrong implementation rather than my one request*" we try to focus on your code and your wording to correctly understand your request. For me confusing part was "I just want to cancel the line break" when we know that there is no line break, and we ware all trying to explain it to you. So sorry, but wording matters, so next time to avoid such situations please don't only *describe* what you want to do, but *show* example of input and expected results (also including your current, invalid results would be very helpful).

Comment: @Pshemo Sorry for making such a confusion, I will make sure that I add an example next time I ask a question. Thank you